# HTML/PHP form not submitting information to SQL Server?

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is the HTML:

```
<form class="post-form" action="process.php" method="post">
        <label for="vendorname">Vendor Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="vendorname" id="vendorname" placeholder="Vendor Name">

        <label for="location">Location</label>
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Location">

        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Price">

        <label for="billingcycle">Billing Cycle</label>
        <select name="billingcycle" id="billing">
            <option value="monthly" selected>Monthly</option>
            <option value="anually">Anually</option>
        </select>

        <label for="startdate">Contract Start Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate">

        <label for="enddate">Contract End Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate">

        
        <label for="comments">Comments</label>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="40" rows="8" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
        
        <label for="fileselect">Attach File</label>
        <input id="fileselect" name="fileselect" type="file" accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, image, .pdf" />

        <label for="filename">File Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="filename" name="filename"  >
        
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" >
    </form>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
 <?php 

    $vendorname = $_POST['vendorname'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $billingcycle = $_POST['billingcycle'];
    $startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
    $enddate = $_POST['enddate'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $fileselect = $_POST['fileselect'];
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];

    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>""); 
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect("", $connectionInfo) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

    try{
       $query = "INSERT INTO dbName (vendorname, location, price, billingcycle, startdate, enddate, comments, fileselect, filename)
       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
       $parms = array($vendorname, $location, $price, $billingcycle, $startdate, $enddate, $comments, $fileselect, $filename);
       $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $parms);
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        echo $e->Getmessage();
    }

    echo "Submission Successful";
?>
```

I am unable to get the form data to post to the SQL Server database.

Database,UID,PWD are all connected in the php. Still not able to get it working. The form submits successfully. Yet, doesn't enter into SQL database.

Comment: At *process.php* comment everything out and try `var_dump($_POST)`. That will help to narrow down where the problem is

Comment: @user3425506 everything came back correctly when using var_dump.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some debugging data . There obviously is an error occurring at some point.   My assumption is that you *think* `$fileselect = $_POST['fileselect'];` is the same as `$_FILES`

Comment: Does an exception get thrown? What error message are you getting? What do your logs say? What's the value of `$result`?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($query)` to see if it looks like a valid SQL statement and also `var_dump($parms)` to see you are supplying valid values? Also if you just put some strings into *$parms* like this: `$parms = array("vendname", "loc" etc etc)` does that get saved?

Comment: You're echoing "Submission successful" _after_ the non-terminating catch closes, so you can't use it as an indicator of success because it will always run. Move it inside the try (after the call to `sqlsrv_query()`) or add an `exit();` to the catch block.

Comment: I figured it out. I apologize for the ridiculous question! Being that none of you could see my column names in SQLSrv it made it impossible to answer this question.

my $query "Insert Into" file names were incorrect.

Comment: _sigh_ Check the value of `$result`. See [sqlsrv_errors()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php).